# Termux Problem with apt install python of specific version

Tags: python, python-3.x, termux

I am trying to install a python of lower version than 3.11.

I am used `apt install python=3.8`, `apt-get install`, `pkg install` but nothink working...

Termux gives me error "no python version '3.8'". (I wrote the error in my own words, since the exact copy does not matter. it says the same...)

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Answer (score 0):

Older Python versions aren't available in the [official repository](https://packages.termux.dev/). You can however use the [Termux User Repository (TUR)](https://github.com/termux-user-repository/tur) (inspired by the [Arch User Repository (AUR)](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages)):

```
pkg install tur-repo
pkg update
pkg install python3.8
```

Comment: [edited] Alr, it works with $ python3.8 and $ pip3... Thanks!!!